# Can LGPL 2.1 licenses software be re-published under GPL 3.0?

Tags: gpl, lgpl, relicensing

I have software licensed under LGPL 2.1 and I want to modify it and re-publish the whole software under the GPL 3.0 license. Is this legally possible?

I think so, but I'm not completely sure.

[LGPL 2.1](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt) says

> ...3. You may opt to apply the terms of the ordinary GNU General Public
>   License instead of this License to a given copy of the Library.  To do
>   this, you must alter all the notices that refer to this License, so
>   that they refer to the ordinary GNU General Public License, version 2,
>   instead of to this License.  (**If a newer version than version 2 of the
>   ordinary GNU General Public License has appeared, then you can specify
>   that version instead if you wish.**)  Do not make any other change in
>   these notices. ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have interpreted the license correctly. A LGPL v2.1 covered work can be relicensed under GPL v2+, which includes the GPL v3.

The [GPL license compatibility matrix in the GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility) confirms this and explains:

> LGPLv2.1 gives you permission to relicense the code under any version of the GPL since GPLv2.

Comment: Thanks. I remember to have seen the license compatibility matrix at some point in the past but couldn't find it yesterday.